# Print out collection as grouped items

Tags: arrays, ruby, postgresql

So far I have a collection of programmes. A programme has an associated account and there are (currently) *six* different "types" of accounts that a programme can belong to.

I need to be able to dump out all the programmes but group them by the type of account they are.

Something like;

```
Alpha Type;
  - Programme One
  - Programme Two
  - Programme Three
Beta Type;
  - Programme Four
  - Programme Five
Delta Type;
  - Programme Six
```

So far all I have managed is to join the associated table and do an order by the account_type :name

```
<% @programmes.each do |programme| %>
  <%= programme.account_type.name %>
<% end %>
```

Which will print out the programmes in a reasonable order but I don't know how to do the grouping.

I am using Postgres if that actually makes it easier? I am pretty new to both Ruby and Postgres

Answer (score 0):

Actually seem to have cracked this one.

I stumbled over this post on [Enumberable#group_by](http://www.rubyfleebie.com/how-to-display-a-collection-grouped-by-an-attribute-value-in-rails/)

Final code in the controller looks like this;

```
@programmes = "get all programmes.."
@account_names = @programmes.group_by{|programme| programme.account.name}
```

In the view I have;

```
<% @account_names.each_pair do |name, programmes| %>
  <hr>
  <strong><%= name %> programmes</strong>
  <br>
  <% programmes.each do |programme| %>
    <i><%= programme.name %></i><br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Remarkable!